# Entity Framework caching under ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, caching, state

I was trying to find out which Entity Framework objects, if any, remain live after the end of an HTTP request that is being handled by ASP .Net?

i.e. Does an ASP .Net application benefit from any of the Entity Framework caching mechanisms across different requests?

This article describes the operations that are occurring under the hood:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx

So I am wondering whether all of these things are repeated for every http request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to, "Programming Enttity Framework (O'Reilly)" by Julia Lerman, The ObjectContext does NOT survive postbacks